# Sitecore Experience Editor - Edit Related Items Button Not Working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

On a fresh install of 8.1 update 3 of Sitecore, when I am using the experience editor on a page I created, I click on some text, and a popup menu appears near the text. On it, there is a menu item that says 'more', and when I click that, I see a button that says 'edit the related item in the content editor'.

[image: Fresh Experience Editor]

and when I click on 'more':

[image: more clicked]

You can see it says 'edit related item'

On an upgraded 8.1 update 3 (I upgraded from SC7) the experience editor does not have a 'more' button, the 'edit the related item' button is disabled (I can click it, but it does nothing).

[image: how it looks in the upgraded version - edit related item not working]

If I swap out the core database from the upgraded server to the fresh one (but keep master/web) then it works as normal, so clearly there is something missing in my core that wasn't upgraded correctly.

I've tried copying templates, layouts, application, everything I could think of (even at the root level) from core, and using the 'overwrite' option, but I can't get it.

Comment: If you have your Sitecore changes serialized (using TDS or Unicorn) then you _could_ just attach a fresh Core DB and re-sync. Only data you should need to copy across is the ASPNET Membership tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option for you in my opinion is to use Razl and compare fresh core db with your upgraded one.

Recently I upgraded project from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.1upd3 and after comparing core dbs with Razl I spotted a lot of differences, especially a lot of missing or different items under /sitecore/system/Dictionary.

The 'Edit the related item' button is here: /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common Field Buttons/Edit related item

Comment: ok thanks. I don't have the budget to buy it but will look at that location (although I did a full package of /sitecore/content/application/* with subitems) and then installed that package with overwrite option. If I did that, you'd agree that would copy everything right?

Comment: I'm going to give you the credit but this was the reason. At
 /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Common Field Buttons/Edit related item node, in the 'data' section, there is a field called 'type'. In the fresh install, it was selected as 'common' on the dropdownlist for a value. On the upgraded, there was nothing selected. By changing the value to 'common', and saving, it worked! Thanks!